# How to restore a php session during Stripe Oauth process

Tags: php, stripe-payments

So, I appear to be losing all of the $_SESSION info during the Stripe Oauth process, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

When Stripe redirects the user back to my website, it is passing the code and state info propperly in the URL, but because the $_SESSION info is lost, my user is logged out in the process.

And yes, when they land on the page from the redirect, I begin the page with  `session_start();`

The user is not closing thier browswer during this process, so I don't understand why it would happen.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible the callback URL is different. If a visitor on your website is using www.example.com and the callback from Stripe goes to example.com (without www) session/cookie data will be lost.

Comment: I know the stripe redirect is http://www.example.com (with the http and the www).

But I don't know what to do about it on my end so that the cookie data is not lost?